# integral, matrices, exponentiation, upper bound, time,linear system, unclear derivation

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, definite-integrals, initial-value-problems

How do I derive from $\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)+Bu(t), x(0)=p$ that

$x(t;p)=e^{At}p+\int_0^t e^{A(t-s)}Bu(s)ds$ ?

Here $A$ and $B$ are matrices of suitable sizes: $A$ is $n\times n$ and $B$ is $n \times m$,both constant real matrices, and $\dot{x}$ is derivation of $x(t)$ by $t$.

Comment: variation of constants: define $y(t)$ by $y(t)=e^{-At}x(t)$ (i.e. $x(t)=e^{At}y(t)$), find the ODE satisfied by $y(t)$, and solve it

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Unfortunately it is too coarse for me to see the solution to my question.What shall I do with $u$ there?

Comment: Start with the homogeneous equation, as explained by user8268, then try to find a particular solution for the non-homogeneous equation (the one including $u$), using methods analogous to the single-variable case.

Comment: $dx/dt=d(e^{At}y)/dt=e^{At}(dy/dt+Ay)=e^{At}dy/dt+Ax$ and this should be equal to $Ax+Bu$, hence the equation for $y$ is $dy(t)/dt=e^{-At}Bu(t)$ - now just integrate to find $y(t)$ (don't forget an arbitrary constant) and get back $x(t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my derivation:

from

$\dot x(t) = Ax(t) + Bu(t) \tag{1}$

we write

$\dot x(t) - Ax(t) = Bu(t), \tag{2}$

and multiply through by $e^{-At}$:

$e^{-At}(\dot x(t) - Ax(t)) = e^{-At}Bu(t); \tag{3}$

the left-hand side may be written

$e^{-At}(\dot x(t) - Ax(t)) = e^{-At}\dot x(t) - e^{-At}Ax(t), \tag{4}$

and we note that

$\dfrac{d}{dt}(e^{-At}x(t)) =  e^{-At}\dot x(t) - Ae^{-At}x(t) = e^{-At}\dot x(t) - e^{-At}Ax(t); \tag{5}$

combining (3), (4), and (5) we find

$\dfrac{d}{dt}(e^{-At}x(t)) = e^{-At}Bu(t); \tag{6}$

we integrate (6) 'twixt $0$ and $t$, *viz*.

$e^{-At}x(t) - e^{-A(0)}x(0) = \displaystyle \int_0^t \dfrac{d}{ds}(e^{-As}x(s))ds = \displaystyle \int_0^t e^{-As}Bu(s)ds; \tag{7}$

we observe that

$e^{-A(0)}x(0) = e^0x(0) = Ix(0) = x(0) = p, \tag{8}$

which we bring over to the right-hand side:

$e^{-At}x(t) = p + \displaystyle \int_0^t e^{-As}Bu(s)ds; \tag{9}$

now a final multiplication by $e^{At}$ reveals

$x(t)  = e^{At}p + e^{At}\displaystyle \int_0^t e^{-As}Bu(s)ds; \tag{10}$

so at last,

$e^{At}\displaystyle \int_0^t e^{-As}Bu(s)ds = \displaystyle \int_0^t e^{At}e^{-As}Bu(s)ds = \displaystyle \int_0^t e^{A(t - s)}Bu(s)ds; \tag{11}$

and ***voila***:

$x(t)  = e^{At}p + \displaystyle \int_0^t e^{A(t - s)}Bu(s)ds. \tag{12}$

Comment: Fiat Lux!   Well done as always. It tickles me that you're taking an integral *'twixt 0 and t*.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom:  Thank you my friend!

Comment: I understand each step but for what it means in English " 'twixt 0 and t " and "voila". Thank you a lot for that detailed answer.

Comment: "'twixt" is an archaic English word for "between", as in the idiomatic phrase "betwixt and between".

Comment: @user122424:  And "voila" is a word the English borrowed from the French; it means, roughly, "there it is!" or "look here!"